# Properly adjusting jQuery to support dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html

Not really sure how to address this, but here goes.

Say you can perform a procedure in jQuery when clicking button `.btn`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){...});
});
```

This works on all `.btn` elements that were present when the document was ready. When we need to get this to work for **dynamically** loaded `.btn` elements, we need to address these elements **through** a static object that contains the dynamically loaded elements first, i.e. `.static-container`:

```
$(".static-container")
    .on("click", ".btn", function(){...});
});
```

However, *any* static element will do, not just the closest one to the element, meaning `body` as well, or a commonly used `#page-wrapper` or something like that.

I have a set of callbacks like this that I wish to include on multiple pages that may have different architectures, so I need some kind of container that appears on every page, which means I can be less specific.

My question is :

How much faster is it to be more specific (meaning: how much deeper in the DOM tree) when specifying a static container? What is good practice in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use the closest possible static parent element to the dynamic content, i.e. as deep in the DOM tree as possible.

The result of this is that the event has fewer elements to bubble through, hence is handled faster. In real terms it's a difference of milliseconds, but who wouldn't want the fastest code possible.

Also note that it's important not to just put all delegated event handlers on a single root element (such as the `document`, `body`, or shared container) as this can lead to some slowdown if there are a multitude of event handlers on a single element. It's for this reason that `live()` was deprecated and removed several years ago.

Comment: I thought as much. Does it make sense to pass this closest static parent as a parameter or should I just organise my HTML to fit this principle? Also; if I shouldn't put them in the same root element, should I do the same here? My jQuery was self-taught and most code samples start with `$(document).ready()`, which is why I sort of took over.

Comment: In your case I would use it with a single element which you can guarantee will exist on all pages. It may result in slightly more bubbling, but the code will be easier to maintain and clearer.